# Identify phone caller in Twilio video room

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-video

I'm using Twilio Programmable Voice to connect a caller to a Programmable Video Room via the Room verb. How can I get the ParticipantIdentity of the caller on the video side?

I see the phone caller's identity on the video side is their phone number dash some numbers. Alternatively, how can I get the caller's number/identity on the voice side.

Basically, I'm looking to determine who the phone caller is on the video side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can [set the identity that comes through for the voice participant](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/adding-programmable-voice-participants-video-rooms#setting-the-voice-participants-identity) by using the `participantIdentity` attribute on the `<Room>` element. The identity will then be readable as the `participant.identity` on the video side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Connect>
    <Room participantIdentity='alice'>RoomName</Room>
  </Connect>
</Response>
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I don't see this behavior in my version. The identity ends up as my phone number with some extra characters after it on the video side. C# Twilio v5.31.3, Twilio.AspNet.Common v5.20.1, Twilio.AspNet.Mvc v5.20.1, twilio-video.js v1.14.1. I'm using response.Say("...").Append(new Connect().Append(new Room { Name = "...", Participantidentity = "<GUID>" }))

Comment: OK, so support let me know that Participantidentity should be ParticipantIdentity (with a capital I). So it looks like the Room class exposes a misspelled property. I'll answer this question with the workaround when I get a response. Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like the incorrect `Participantidentity` was [changed in June](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/commit/99be66c6280ae26a3b7d5ab0a98c940a4e03df29#diff-9c0a68c5e16644c4f17df34f2c32ee1b) for version 5.30.0. You can see that in [the docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-csharp/5.30.0/class_twilio_1_1_twi_m_l_1_1_voice_1_1_room.html) too.

Comment: That's good news! Would you mind marking the answer as correct so that other people can see it helped too? Thanks!